# create-react-app docker: client-side routing not working, nginx welcome page displayed instead

Tags: docker, nginx, single-page-application, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I'm new to docker and trying to dockerize my react app (it is working well with express.js).
After having looked at a number of similar issues on stackoverflow, I've decided to post my question. Here is my `Dockerfile` (at the root of my react project):

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12.16-stretch-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src/
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn config list &  yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.17.8 AS final
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /src/public /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /src/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here is my custom nginx config file which should enable client-side routing:
`default.conf` (at root of my react project):

```
server {                                                                             
    listen       80;                                                                 
    server_name  localhost;                                                          
                                                                                     
    location / {                                                                     
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;                                                
        index  index.html index.htm;  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;                                               
    }                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;                                         
    location = /50x.html {                                                           
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Now after I have built the image, I run it at `http://localhost:3000`. This is what I see when I access the url from my browser (instead of the real home page):

[image]

So what am I doing wrong here?
(My docker is the latest stable version, I just downloaded official site)
Thank for your suggestions.

Comment: The setup [here](https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe) works for me, if you want to compare and contrast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could not get your config to work with mine (had to make some changes: use yarn instead of npm, remove some lines not relevant in my case). But I'm getting an error when the line 'RUN yarn build' is executed:
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn build' returned a non-zero code: 1
But yarn build works fine outside of dockerfile